# Error Updating and installing packages ubuntu

Tags: installation, 13.04, updates

I was trying to install git in my ubuntu using application manager.and got a "Required installation of untrusted packages error".i followed a few forums and tried to run `sudo apt-get update`and i got this error

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                                                                                                
  Could not connect to 172.16.0.20:8080 (172.16.0.20), connection timed out
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                                                                                            
  Could not connect to 172.16.0.20:8080 (172.16.0.20), connection timed out
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg                                                                      
  Could not connect to 172.16.0.20:8080 (172.16.0.20), connection timed out
Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                                                                     
  Could not connect to 172.16.0.20:8080 (172.16.0.20), connection timed out
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg                                                                     
  Unable to connect to 172.16.0.20:8080:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 172.16.0.20:8080:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.0.20:8080 (172.16.0.20), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 172.16.0.20:8080:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 172.16.0.20:8080:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.0.20:8080 (172.16.0.20), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.0.20:8080 (172.16.0.20), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 172.16.0.20:8080 (172.16.0.20), connection timed out

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

i thought it was a problem with the network connection and tried pinging google.com and it was working perfectly.Can anyone please help me with this.i am new to ubuntu